# Where can I download Microsoft's complete list of software SKUs?

Tags: microsoft-office

Microsoft periodically publishes an Excel (how ironic) spreadsheet listing the SKUs / part numbers of all of their software.  It has the sku number, product description, etc.  (The spreadsheet is so large that rumor has it Microsoft had to expand the number of rows Excel could handle just for this one document.)

Comment: That's not irony.

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: @Keltari: I guess the question is in the title ;)

Comment: who has time to read titles? :D

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge there is no complete list - if so please send it to me :-)
Try price lists: you can find the latest retail price list online. https://partner.microsoft.com/US/licensing/licuspricelists Those do not include enterprise skus. Ask your vendor/LAR for a volume license list. They provide such lists. At least for the part you are eligible.